# Testng, ошибка при параллелизации в @AfterMethod. Java+Testng+Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

Есть @AfterMethod, который проверяет сумму чисел в двух чеках после каждого тестового метода, при создании документа числа в чеках меняются. @AfterMethod проверяет в начале чек_1 и далее чек_2, но при параллелизации получается так, что число из чек_1 записывается в память, и пока осуществляется переход к чек_2 другой тест меняет значение обоих чеков. Я пробовал добавить synchronized к методу, но это не помогло.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите код теста